# How to keep sitecore alive out of the box implementation

Tags: .net, design-patterns, sitecore, keep-alive

How to keep Sitecore instance alive using Sitecore keepalive service, I am looking for an out-of-box solution with no dependency on the hosted application or the hosted windows server(e.g task schedulers).

I have a staging server which goes idle after 20 min(application pool settings) of scheduled application pool recycle. This affects production WFFM save actions not getting executed because it runs on a staging server. Since staging is only accessed by me mostly so the forms are down on weekends and this cause business loss. Until someone explicitly accesses staging site the forms are down, but post this it works well till the next application pool recycle.

Sitecore:8.2 update 1,
WFFM 8.2
IIS:6.2

The Sitecore keep-alive UrlAgent does help but in shutdown state, even this does not work.

I know multiple articles suggests going for out of box implementation like power-shell script with windows task scheduler, but that's a dependency and if we decide to move away from current server to other implementation then no one will ever know about this, or if I move away from this project than who would remember this setting.

So basically I need to implement keep-alive in a design pattern that is more robust and does not require additional steps to carry out other than application deployment, something like deploying it and forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for [IIS 8.0 Application Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) to set an [application to always run](https://serverfault.com/questions/828200/difference-between-start-application-pool-immediately-and-start-mode-alwaysrun).